# Firebase: Useful for web applications?

Tags: database, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a web application that is very data intensive; at the apex there could be a data table with 15 columns and 500 rows.

I want to use firebase along with angular for the purposes of getting it done quickly but will later use a Java ee backend.

Firebase [emphasizes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore)   that their databases are for mobile app development, will I run into major if I try to use it for this app? Are there any major differences between their databases and other nosql ones i should be aware of?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Firebase basically takes the back-end portion of programming out of the equation and allows for easy database storage/retrieval. You can absolutely use it with a web application as I have built a website using it as the back-end storage.

Comment: 15 columns and 500 rows is a trivial amount of data - but it could be a huge amount of data depending on what is stored in each 'cell' so no real way to evaluate that. Firebase is blisteringly fast and, depending on use case, can easily handle what you are asking so there would be no need to leverage another database as well. Unfortunately opinion or recommendation type questions are off topic here.  I would suggest going through the [Firebase Getting Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/guides/) guide and getting familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks guys! I am quite familiar with firebase; I currently host a website on it. I was curios if it will be just as fast if multiple users are pulling sizable amount of different data at the same time.

Comment: It is just as fast but your question doesn't mention a use case other than *apex there could be a data table with 15 columns and 500 rows* - no mention of what data is contained in the table (bytes?, megabytes?) and/or number of users so it's kinda hard to answer.